# Build several targets from 1 project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2010.

I have a dll project that i need to build several times with various define. 
The code don't change between the build nor the compilation options.

More precisly i'd like when I hit build to get : 
library1.dll with #define LIBRARY_NUMBER 1 
library2.dll with #define LIBRARY_NUMBER 2 
library3.dll with #define LIBRARY_NUMBER 3 
library4.dll with #define LIBRARY_NUMBER 4 
library5.dll with #define LIBRARY_NUMBER 5

Actually i do this manually, is there a way to automate this process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The default configuration in Visual Studio has `Debug` and `Release` configurations,
but you should create your own configurations (call them `Config1`...`Config5`).

Then go to the Build menu / Batch Build, where it will list all your configurations.
Check the checkboxes by the ones you want to build, and hit "Build".

Each configuration will be built in turn.